# Calling statistics functions from Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This may well be completely trivial.

I want to call the spearmanr function from scipy: (the data are just examples)

```
import scipy
from numpy import *

Len = [2,3,5,7,2]
Pop = [5,2,6,3,2]

a = array(Len)
b = array(Pop)

print scipy.stats.spearmanr(a,b)
```

This generates the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spearmanr'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `import scipy.stats`. Then it works. Importing a package does not automatically import all the subpackages/modules. In these cases you have to do this explicitly.

Comment: Why is that needed when you can access members of the `os.path` module when importing `os` on its own? Does `os` automatically import `os.path`?

Comment: Yes, it appears that it does. This is up to the package.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y hmm when I try this its giving me a different error... "no matching architecture in universal wrapper" Could you post your entire correct modification of my code?

Comment: @Will: The code as you posted, with my single modification of the `import`-statement works fine for me. This seems to be an issue with your installation of SciPy.

Comment: @Jab: That is needed because scipy employs lazy import to reduce the startup time.